# Salesforce method is not fully executed

Tags: salesforce, apex, salesforce-communities

My code essentially does what I want until the part where I want to write back the response Id to Salesforce.

```
public class ExpensifyCallout {
    //@future(callout=true)
    public static void createReport(Id SFReportID, String projectName, Date projectStartDate, Date projectEndDate, String projectReportLocation, String policyID, String employeeEmail){

        Http http = new Http();
        HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
        request.setEndpoint('callout:Expensify_API');    
        request.setHeader('ContentType', 'application/json');    
        request.setBody('requestJobDescription={"type": "create","credentials": {"partnerUserID": "{!$Credential.Username}" ,"partnerUserSecret": "{!$Credential.Password}"},"inputSettings": {"type": "report","policyID": "'+policyID+'","report": {"title": "'+projectName+'/ '+projectStartDate.format()+' - '+projectEndDate.format()+'/ '+projectReportLocation+'"},  "employeeEmail": "'+employeeEmail+'", "expenses":[]}}');
        request.setMethod('POST');
        HttpResponse response = http.send(request);
        // If the request is successful, parse the JSON response.
        if (response.getStatusCode() == 200) {
           System.debug(response.getBody());
           Map <String, Object> responseJSON = (Map <String, Object>) JSON.deserializeUntyped(response.getBody());
           String reportID = string.valueof(responseJSON.get('reportID'));
           System.debug('Hello World! ');
           System.debug('Hello World! '+ reportID);

           /*ExpensifyReport__c[] eRecords = [SELECT Name
                                   FROM ExpensifyReport__c
                                   WHERE Id = :SFReportID];
           ExpensifyReport__c e = eRecords[0];
           e.expensifyReportID__c = reportID;*/
        }
        // else handle problem
    }
```

My response code from the api is the following:
`{"reportID":"54995495","reportName":"My TEST report","responseCode":200}`
and I want to retrieve the reportID and write it back to the record I created that triggered the callout.

Only the two statements with Hello World in it are not printed. The rest works as expected. Does anyone have an idea why this could be? Many thanks.

I noticed an error message which does not help me much:
`Invalid api version:0.0` 
When I check in the Settings none of the listed apis has version 0.0 ...

Comment: The error suggests to me that your Named Credential is configured incorrectly and has the wrong URL.

Comment: The request is successful though. I also get the response I expect. What lets you conclude that this error message comes from the credentials?

Comment: I presumed that your "hello world" messages were not printing because the call failed with a result code >= 300. If that's not the case, perhaps you could edit the question to add some information. Note that there are success codes that are not 200 (e.g. 204)

Answer (score 0):

I've verified your code runs fine with the following test:

```
HttpResponse response = new HttpResponse();
response.setBody('{"reportID":"54995495","reportName":"My TEST report","responseCode":200}');

Map <String, Object> responseJSON = (Map <String, Object>) JSON.deserializeUntyped(response.getBody());
String reportID = string.valueof(responseJSON.get('reportID'));
System.debug('The reportId is: '+ reportId);
```

Your API version issue can be resolved by:
Setup -> Apex Classes -> *Click on your Apex class* -> Edit -> Version Settings -> Change the API version to anything other than it's current value. -> Change it back to the appropriate API version.